# how to remove a line from a string with large content in C++?

Tags: c++

i have a string with following content:

```
string myString;
cout<<"String  :"<<endl<<myString<<endl;
```

Output is :

```
String :
/this/is/first/line/library.so
cv_take_Case::newFuncton(int const&)
cv_take_Case::anotherMethod(char const&)
thi_is::myMethod
.
.
.
sdfh dshf j dsjfh sdjfh
```

so in above example, how to remove the entire line containing "newFuncton" string.

Comment: Where is the string?  (That is, what is your input?)

Comment: How did you come by this string in the first place? Maybe you can just avoid reading that line in.

Comment: have you tried C++ regular expressions?  see this link: http://www.johndcook.com/cpp_regex.html

Comment: @John, "myString" is string variable containing large content, with each line terminated by newline character. i have to find a sub-string "newFunction" and remove that entire line.

Comment: @BSalunke if the string you are searching for is always at the start of the line, then jrok's answer will be the best for you, because mine involves the overhead of finding the newline behind the text you want as well as ahead of it, whereas his only needs to know the newline ahead of it, because it assumes that the text you are searching for is at the beginning of the line.

Comment: @Seth Carnegie Asumptions make our lifes easier. But format specification would be even better :)

Comment: @jrok well they may make the answerer's life easier, but not the asker's :) Each of the answers are good under different conditions, but unfortunately we don't have all the conditions.

Comment: @SetCarnegie. Can't argue with that, so I made my assumption clear in the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One way would be

1. Use `string::find` to locate the text `newFunction` in the string
2. Use `string::find` again but starting from where you found `newFunction` and search for the next `'\n'`
3. Use `string::rfind` starting from the beginning of the string and ending at the position of `newFunction` for the previous `'\n'`
4. Use `string::erase` to remove the text between the two newlines, leaving only one newline.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string text = "hello\nblahafei fao ef\nthis is a string\nhello newFunction stuff\nasdfefe\nnopef";

    size_t nFPos = text.find("newFunction");
    size_t secondNL = text.find('\n', nFPos);
    size_t firstNL = text.rfind('\n', nFPos);

    cout << "Original string: " << '\n' << text << '\n' << endl;

    text.erase(firstNL, secondNL - firstNL);

    cout << "Modified string: " << '\n' << text << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Outputs:

```
Original string: 
hello
blahafei fao ef
this is a string
hello newFunction stuff
asdfefe
nopef

Modified string: 
hello
blahafei fao ef
this is a string
asdfefe
nopef
```

Comment: i agree with the answer except for step 3. why not use rfind?

Comment: @OrenS. yeah, that would be better. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: @Seth I have some problem with above solution to my problem. My code is crashes when string that we are searching is present in the first line. rfind() function gives unexpected pointer.Any suggestion to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You might want to organize it in a function, for example:

```
void RemoveLine(std::string& source, const std::string& to_remove)
{
    size_t m = source.find(to_remove);
    size_t n = source.find_first_of("\n", m + to_remove.length());
    source.erase(m, n - m + 1);
}
```

Usage:

```
RemoveLine(myString, std::string("cv_take_Case::newFunction"));
```

Note that I assumed the part we search for will be at the beggining of the line. For a more robust solution look at Seth Carnegie's answer.

Answer (score 2):

It depends, if you know you are removing the second line, you can do this:

```
auto b = std::find(myString.begin(), myString.end(), '\n');
++b;
auto e = std::find(b, myString.end(), '\n');
++e;
myString.erase(b,e);
```

Comment: Thanks Benjamin for solution, but can you suggest the solution even if the string is not second line.

Comment: @BSalunke: For that, see Seth's answer, or jrok's.  Like I said, it depends.  If you provide more accurate information about your situation, we can provide more accurate answers.  KerrekSB's comment for example might be a solution, but we can't know without more information.

Answer (score 1):

Now that C++11 is out, an easier answer is with regex_replace

```
#include <regex>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

main() {
std::string text = "Stuff\nBla bla SomeFunction bletch\nThings\n";
std::regex badLine("\n.*SomeFunction.*\n");
std::cout << std::regex_replace(text, badLine, "\n");
}
```

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_replace

Comment: Thanks! That's the easiest to deal with and most flexible.